# Most efficient way to track x and y values of multiple object instances on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an arbitrary number of object instances on the stage. At any one given time the number of objects may be between 10 and 50. Each object instance can move, but the movement is gradual, the current coordinates are not predictable and at any given moment I may need to retrieve the coordinates of a specific object instance.

Is there a common best-practice method to use in this case to track object instance coordinates? I can think of two approaches:

1. I write a function within the object class that, upon arbitrary event execution, is called on an object instance and returns that object instances coordinates.
2. Within the object class I declare global static variables that represent x and y values and, upon arbitrary event execution, the variables are updated with the latest values for that object instance.

While I can get both methods to work, I do not know whether one or the other would be detrimental to program performance in the long run. I lean toward the global variables because I expect it is less resource intensive to update and call a variable than to call a function which subsequently updates and calls a variable. Maybe there is even a third option?

I understand that this is a somewhat subjective question. I am asking with respect to resource consumption so please answer in that respect.

Comment: It sounds like you are perhaps prematurely optimizing. Both of the options you present here could be implemented in very fast and very slow ways. Neither is just going to be "faster". One option is to pick an approach, build it, find the bottlenecks in your code and then evaluate where the slow down is occurring.

Comment: I am actually working at the same time that I ask this question.

Comment: So have you pin-pointed the spot in the code that is slow?

Comment: I am not diagnosing an existing problem, I am using feedback here (which has been very helpful so far!) to try to make proper design choices upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand.. The `x` and `y` properties are both stored on the object (if it's a DisplayObject) and readable.. Why do you need to store these in a global or whatever?

If you're not using `DisplayObject` as a base, then just create the properties yourself with appropriate getters.

If you want to get the coordinates of all your objects, add them to an array, let's say `objectList`.

Then just use a loop to check the values:

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in objectList)
{
    trace(i.x, i.y);
}
```

I think I'm misunderstanding the question, though.

Comment: Your knowledge is beyond mine, clearly :) I have one object class that defines an object. There is a main class that adds it to the stage and a third class that needs to know the x and y values of the first object instance. I understand that it should be in DisplayObject if it is on the stage. An array would be a good way to track everything added to stage. If I have an array in one class, then how might another class access that array? Sorry for not mentioning classes earlier, I didn't realize it was relevant.

Comment: Ah, so what you can do here is define the array in whichever class is creating the objects. I'd put `objectList.push(your_object)` straight after `addChild(your_object)`

Comment: So if the second class is calling addChild(object) and the third class needs to know the x and y of the object that I pushed to the array.. would the array be a global or am I missing something obvious still?

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going with this now, sorry. A good practise here it to have a type of **core** class that will store stuff like this. From here, each of your objects should have reference to this core class. The core class then also has reference to other classes like a data manager, etc. To keep it simple, I'd just make the array in this core class. When you create your object, just define your reference to the core class. Now in your object you should be able to do something like `core.objectList` to reference the array.

Comment: Ah hah! This puts both of my approaches to shame. I didn't see this. Great input and thanks for showing me what I didn't realize. Thank you!

Comment: I actually have a small framework I created a while back to cater for this stuff at project start if you'd like to give that a try?

Answer (score 1):

definitely 1.
for code readability use a get property, ie

```
public function get x():Number { return my_x; }
```

The problem with 2, is you may well also need to keep track of which object those coords are for - not to mention it is just messy... Globals can get un-managable quickly, hence all this reesearch into OOP and encapsuilation, and doing away with (mostly) the need for globals..

with only 50 or less object - don't even consider performance issues...

And remember that old mantra - "Premature optimisation is the root of programming evil" ;-)

Comment: 50 objects is pretty trivial - I mean if you check out http://projectavian.com/ you'll see 4000 objects moving nicely without trouble (not to mention that `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` and `Math.atan2()` are also being run on each of these objects to update the positioning).